# Why executes MariaDB all subqueries in select-statement before order by keyword, even if they are not necessary?

Tags: mysql, sql, mariadb, subquery, sql-order-by

we switched our database from mySQL8 to MariaDB10 a week ago and now we have massive performance problems. We figured out why: we are working with subqueries in select statements and `ORDER BY` pretty often. Here is an example:

```
SELECT id, (SELECT id2 FROM table2 INNER JOIN [...] WHERE column.foreignkey = table.id) queryResult
FROM table
WHERE status = 5
ORDER BY column
LIMIT 10
```

imagine, there are 1.000.000 entries in `table` which are affected if `status = 5`.

**What happens in mySQL8:** `ORDER BY` and `LIMIT` execute and after that the subquery (10 rows affected)

**What happens in MariaDB10:** the subquery executes (1.000.000 rows affected) and after that `ORDER BY` and `LIMIT`

Both queries are returning 10 rows but under MariaDB10 it is incredible slow because of that. Why is this happing? And is there an option in MariaDB which we should activate to avoid this? I know from mySQL8 that select subqueries will be executed when they are mentioned in **ORDER BY**. But if not they will be executed when the resultset is there.

Info: if we do this, everything is fine:

```
SELECT *, (SELECT id2 FROM table2 INNER JOIN [...] WHERE column.foreignkey = outerTable.id) 
FROM (
    SELECT id
    FROM table
    WHERE status = 5
    ORDER BY column
    LIMIT 10
) outerTable
```

Thank you so much for any help.

Comment: Please provide `EXPLAIN SELECT ...` for both versions.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After searching and searching I finally found a solution to make the mariaDB10 database working as I knew it from mySQL8.

For those which have similar problems: set this each time you connect to the server and everything works like in mySQL8:

```
SET optimizer_use_condition_selectivity = 1
```

Long version: the problem I described at the top was suddenly solved and the subquery was executed like it was in the past under mySQL8. I did exactly nothing!

But there were soon new problems: we have a statistic page, which was incredible slow. I noticed that an index was missing and I add it. I executed the query and it was working. Without index 100.000 rows affected for finding the results, after adding 38. Well done.

Then strange things started to happen: I executed the query again and the database didn't use the index. So I executed it again and again. This was the result:

1st query execution (I did it with `ANALYZE`): 100.000 rows affected

2nd query execution: 38 rows affected

3rd query execution: 38 rows affected

4th query execution: 100.000 rows affected

5th query execution: 100.000 rows affected

It was complete random, even in our SaaS solution! So I startet to search how the optimizer determine an execution plan. I found this: [optimizer_use_condition_selectivity](https://mariadb.com/docs/reference/mdb/system-variables/optimizer_use_condition_selectivity/)

the default for mariaDB10.4 server is 4 which means, that histograms are used to calculate the result set. I saw a few videos about it and recognized that this will not work in our case (although we stuck to database normalization). Mode 1 works well:

> use selectivity of index backed range conditions to calculate the cardinality of a partial join if the last joined table is accessed by full table scan or an index scan

I hope this will help some other guys which despair with this like I did.

Answer (score 1):

This is because table a by nature unsorted bunch of rows

> A "table" (and subquery in the FROM clause too) is - according to the SQL standard - an unordered set of rows. Rows in a table (or in a subquery in the FROM clause) do not come in any specific order. That's why the optimizer can ignore the ORDER BY clause that you have specified. In fact, the SQL standard does not even allow the ORDER BY clause to appear in this subquery (we allow it, because ORDER BY ... LIMIT ... changes the result, the set of rows, not only their order).

[mariadb manual](https://mariadb.com/kb/en/why-is-order-by-in-a-from-subquery-ignored/)

So the optimizer removes and ignores the ORDER BY.

You found already a method to circumvent it using LIMIT and ORDER By in the subquery

Comment: do you know the reason why mySQL8 allows/implement it? And what it is called there? Searching for a workaround, because that would be many changes for us ;-) Or would you regard to remodel it?

Comment: mysql some times deviates from the standard, and many "old" queries depend on it and nobody will really piss of all mysql developer. this (but not only this)is  which makes a switch between rdms difficult and cost a lot of man power.

Comment: That quotation is irrelevant, I think.  The `ORDER BY` cannot be removed because that would affect which 10 rows are used.  The quote comes from using a derived table to do "groupwise-max".

Answer (score 0):

At 5.6, MariaDB and MySQL went off in different directions for the Optimizer.  MariaDB focused a lot on subqueries, though perhaps to the detriment of this particular query.

Do you have `INDEX(status, column)`?  It would help most variants of this query.

Answer (score -1):

Yes, the subquery has to be evaluated for every row *before* the `order by`.  The subquery only seems to need `id`, so you can phrase this as:

```
SELECT id,
       (SELECT id2 FROM table2 INNER JOIN [...] WHERE column.foreignkey = t.id) as queryResult
FROM (SELECT t.*
      FROM table t
      WHERE status = 5
      ORDER BY column
      LIMIT 10
     ) t
```

This evaluates the subquery only after the rows have been selected from the table.

Comment: Probably unwise to do `t.*` instead of just the columns that will be used.

Comment: @RickJames . . . (1) That is a microoptimization, particularly if there is an index on `(status, column)`.  (2) The OP has not made it clear what is in the subquery and it could be correlated to other columns.  This does not break the query.